# How do I find out my SSD/HDD's RPM?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

If I wanted to find out the RPM speed of my SSD and my HDD, how would I do that? Is there a program or something built into Windows?

Comment: Your SSD should have a RPM of 0. If it is greater something is really gone wrong.

Comment: Thomas is pulling your leg, mugen.

Comment: [CrystalDiskInfo tells the rotational speed of hard drives](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/crystaldiskinfo_portable), SSD drives have no spinning platters so there is no rpm rating.

Comment: SSD RPM is OVER 9000

Comment: Scientifically speaking the electrones in the SSD have an rpm of near ∞

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A program called [Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy)
can tell you a lot about the components in your computer, including your hard drive. The free version will do for you. Using it is pretty straightforward: fire it up, wait for it to scan and view the information.

Answer (score 0):

The Solid State Drive Don't have RPM.
Normal Hard Drives with spinning platters do that is why Performance is measured in RPM - Revolutions Per Minute, this means depends how fast your disks spin in the Hard Drive it Improves your Performance, however it also depends what connection technology your drive has if the drives are using the latest connections then your HDD - RPM - Motherboard - Raid Config will make the total difference. to find out what hardware you have installed you can

Right Click on My Computer -> Manage -> Device Manager -> Disk Drives

you will find your Hard Drives just copy the device name for example: M4-CT128M4SSD2

And search on google you will find under tech specs all the information.

Second way is to power off your PC remove your power cord -> touch a touch a metal object to discharge static electricity, before you touch any components,
remove the drive and there will be a sticker on it that says the model number and rpm.

SSD work in different way they have no spinning platters and the Performance depends on the Technology of the connection to the motherboard and the read and write speeds and if you have an Raid setup this can improve performance depending on the raid configuration.

I hope this helps you and others.